# How to lock the position of some component in a scroll pane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have created a scroll pane and add some component inside scroll pane but I want to lock the position of some component when I scroll the scroll pane. If it is possible then how can I do this?

Comment: *"If it is possible then how can I do this?"* Put those components **outside** the scroll pane.

Comment: Do you mean you want something like "fixed" rows and "fixed" columns - like in Excel?

Comment: but i want to put those component inside scroll pane as like webpages when scroll the page header position fixed

Comment: @ritu Perhaps you should have a look at [How to use scroll panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) which contains examples of using the header sections of the scroll pane